# Thermodynamic Estimation of Flame Temperature

Tags: thermodynamics, physical-chemistry, rocket-science

I am trying to create a simulation program for the internals of a solid rocket motor, and I would like to know how you can theoretically predict the burning temperature of a propellant based on the composition of it, in one case I would have Potassium Nitrate and Sucrose, and Dextrose etc. Now I know that you can find the burning temperatures of those online but I also would like to know if there is any analysis you can do to determine it yourself without empirically testing it. Anything is much appreciated!

Comment: I recommend reading [the Wikipedia article on adiabatic flame temperature](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adiabatic_flame_temperature). It seems to offer the type of information you are looking for, given you are familiar with basic chemical thermodynamics (1st law of thermodynamics, various thermodynamic processes, how to estimate enthalpy of reaction from bond energies etc.).

Comment: In your case combustion will be turbulent, so just forget about theoretical predictions! Your best hope is to get tables and plots of empirical data, which are hopefully non-dimensionalized.